# regex select tag td only with specific property

Tags: php, regex

so i have this html table:

```
$table = '<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="calendar">
    <tr>
        <th>Sun</th>
        <th>Mon</th>
        <th>Tue</th>
        <th>Wed</th>
        <th>Thu</th>
        <th>Fri</th>
        <th>Sat</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td data-date="12/01/2014">
            <div class="wrapper">
                <div class="day">1</div>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td data-date="12/02/2014">
            <div class="wrapper">
                <div class="day">2</div>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td data-date="12/03/2014">
            <div class="wrapper">
                <div class="day">3</div>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td data-date="12/04/2014" class="green">
            <div class="wrapper">
                <div class="day">4</div>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td data-date="12/05/2014" class="green">
            <div class="wrapper">
                <div class="day">5</div>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td data-date="12/06/2014" class="green">
            <div class="wrapper">
                <div class="day">6</div>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td data-date="12/07/2014" class="green">
            <div class="wrapper">
                <div class="day">7</div>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td data-date="12/08/2014" class="green">
            <div class="wrapper">
                <div class="day">8</div>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td data-date="12/09/2014" class="green">
            <div class="wrapper">
                <div class="day">9</div>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td data-date="12/10/2014" class="green">
            <div class="wrapper">
                <div class="day">10</div>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td data-date="12/11/2014" class="green">
            <div class="wrapper">
                <div class="day">11</div>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td data-date="12/12/2014">
            <div class="wrapper">
                <div class="day">12</div>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td data-date="12/13/2014">
            <div class="wrapper">
                <div class="day">13</div>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>';
```

i want to get the date inside `data-date` property in tag `<td>` which has no property `class="green"`. the valid results expected are:

```
12/01/2014
12/02/2014
12/03/2014
12/12/2014
12/13/2014
```

(they are not have property `class="green"`)

this my code:

```
preg_match_all('/<td[^>]*data-date="(.*?)">(.*?)<\/td>/', $table, $tag, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
print_r($tag);
```

however the regex i used is still match with tag `<td>` which has property `class="green"`. since i want to exclude theme, what is the correct regex?

need your advise, thank you for helping.

Comment: Wouldn't a parser, like `DOMDocument`, be more appropriate than a regex ?

Comment: In particular when you're unversed with regex. (Nitpick: DOMDoc is not a parser, just a traversal frontend to libxml. Not regularily the most practical frontend, btw).  -- Your shown regex wouldn't match anything with the shown input - due to absent `/s` flag. And even then it would require further constraints to both `.*?`, or else *extracts* neighboring tag run-ins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I try this :

```
/<td[^>]*data-date="([0-9\/]+)">(.*?)<\/td>/s
```

and it looks like it does the job,
Use https://fr.functions-online.com/preg_match_all.html to test your regexp ;)

<sub>Sorry for my english</sub>

Comment: thank you pkshetlie, it's suitable for my case. also thanks to vks, mario, adeneo.

Comment: @FatimahWulandari this wll not match `<td data-date="12/03/2014" class="notgreen">` is this intended?

Answer (score 1):

```
<td[^>]*data-date="[^"]*"(?:(?!class="green"|>).)*>(.*?)<\/td>
```

Try this.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/dU7oN5/9